# How to retrieve the selected drop down value on the same page using submit button

Tags: php, javascript

I am working on a form that has 6 chkboxes and depending on the selection of chkboxes (multiple selection allowed) particular divs are getting displayed. And each div contain some questions (In the form of dropdown boxes & these values are given hardcore & not from DB).  For this I used javascript. Everything is going as expected. But now I want to add submit button (on submit result should display on the same page) & on submitting the form I want to display the selected dropdown values.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance...

Here is my tried code -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
        var showClasses = { };
        function fnchecked(blnchecked,className)
        {
            if(blnchecked)
            {
                showClasses[className] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                showClasses[className] = false;
            }
            var ps = document.getElementById("div-block").children;
            var psNumber = ps.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < psNumber; i ++) {
                var have = hasClasses(ps[i], showClasses);
                if (have) {
                    ps[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    ps[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

        function hasClasses(element)
        {
            var result = false;
            for (var cls in showClasses) {
                if (showClasses[cls]) {
                    if ((' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1) {
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div>
        <label>Technologies: </label></br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" onChange="fnchecked(this.checked,'question1');" value="Kingspan Solar" /> Kingspan Solar</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" onChange="fnchecked(this.checked,'question2');" value="Solar PVT" /> Solar PVT</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" onChange="fnchecked(this.checked,'question3');" value="Insulation" /> Insulation</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" onChange="fnchecked(this.checked,'question4');" value="Gas boiler" /> Gas boiler</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" onChange="fnchecked(this.checked,'question5');" value="Oil boiler" /> Oil boiler</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" onChange="fnchecked(this.checked,'question6');" value="Heat recovery ventilation" /> Heat recovery ventilation</br>
         <!--<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Get The Info">--></br>

       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
            {
                $tech = $_POST['technologies'];
                if(empty($tech)) 
                {
                  echo("You didn't select any Technologies.");
                } 
                else
                {
                  $N = count($tech);

                  echo("You selected $N Technology(s): ");
                  for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
                  {
                    echo($tech[$i] . " ");
                  }
                }
            }
        ?>

        <div id="div-block" >
            <p class=" question1 " style="display: none">
                How many people live in the house ?
                <select name="people">
                    <option value="">Click & Choose</option>
                    <option value="people1">1 to 3 (200 litre system)</option>
                    <option value="people2">3 to 4 (250 litre system)</option>
                    <option value="people3">4 to 6 (300 litre system)</option>
                    <option value="people4">6 to 9 (400 litre system)</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p class="question1 question2 question3 question4 question5 question6 " style="display: none">
                What type of house do you live in?
                <select name="house_type">
                    <option value="">Click & Choose</option>
                    <option value="house_type1">Bungalow</option>
                    <option value="house_type2">2 story</option>
                    <option value="house_type3">Dormer</option>
                    <option value="house_type4">3 or 4 story</option>
                    <option value="house_type5">Apartment</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p class="question1 question2  " style="display: none">
                Is your house south facing?
                <select name="house_face">
                    <option value="">Click & Choose</option>
                    <option value="house_face1">South</option>
                    <option value="house_face2">South east or South west</option>
                    <option value="house_face3">East or West</option>
                    <option value="house_face4">No</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p class="question1 question2 question3 question4 question5 " style="display: none">
                Was it built before 2006?
                <select name="built">
                    <option value="">Click & Choose</option>
                    <option value="built1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="built2">No</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p class=" question2 " style="display: none">
                  How many people live at the house ?
                      <select name="people">
                          <option value="">Click & Choose</option>
                          <option value="people1">1-2</option>
                          <option value="people2">3</option>
                          <option value="people3">4</option>
                          <option value="people4">4-6</option>
                          <option value="people4">6-8</option>
                      </select>
                 </p>

            <p class=" question3 " style="display: none">
                Is your house detached?
                <select name="detached">
                    <option value="">Click & Choose</option>
                    <option value="detached1">Detached</option>
                    <option value="detached2">Semi D</option>
                    <option value="detached3">Mid Terrace</option>
                    <option value="detached4">Apartment</option>
                </select>

            </p>

            <p class=" question4 question5 question6 " style="display: none">
                How many bedrooms are in the house?
                <select name="bedroom">
                    <option value="">Click & Choose</option>
                    <option value="bedroom1">1-2</option>
                    <option value="bedroom2">2-3</option>
                    <option value="bedroom3">3-4</option>
                    <option value="bedroom4">4-5</option>
                    <option value="bedroom5">5-8</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p  class=" question4 question5 " style="display: none">
              Do you use gas or oil?
                  <select name="gas_oil">
                      <option value="">Click & Choose</option>
                      <option value="gas_oil1">Gas</option>
                      <option value="gas_oil2">Oil</option>
                  </select>
             </p>
             <p  class=" question4 question5 " style="display: none">
              House you like to upgrade your central heating controls to SEAI standards so you can claim a grant for the works?
                  <select name="upgrade">
                      <option value="">Click & Choose</option>
                      <option value="upgrade1">Yes</option>
                      <option value="upgrade2">No</option>
                  </select>
             </p>
             <p  class=" question6 " style="display: none">
              Is this a new build or total renovation?
                  <select name="upgrade">
                      <option value="">Click & Choose</option>
                      <option value="upgrade1">Yes</option>
                      <option value="upgrade2">No</option>
                  </select>
             </p>
        </div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use button rather than submit

Comment: where do you want to display result? You should improve you question a bit.

Comment: i want to display the result on the same page. And i have written html dropdown so plz help me in that. I dont know how to retrieve html dropdown value in php. and I also need the selected dropdown value id also.

Comment: You say, you want the dropdown value in php, but I guess you want it in Javascript as you want to display on the same page. There is no need to submit your form. With Javascript you can retrieve the selected data and display it elsewhere on your page.

Comment: Leonard, I want to do some calculation on the basis of selected dropdown value & that's why I want the value in php.

Comment: In that case, you can use "print_r($_POST);" to look how PHP knows about the submitted values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code in jsfiddle. Check this by clicking [here](http://jsfiddle.net/67HYa/2/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.checkme').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var val = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.'+val).show();
     }

}); 

$('.submit').click(function(){
    var value = $('.firstCheck').val();
    $('.finalvalue').html(value);
  });
```

});

Comment: Buddy I've written the code in jsfiddle for one div and one checkbox. U'll ve to develop the code for all checkbox and divs.

Comment: Yes dude I knw that & I dont even want you to write the whole code for me. But just tell me where should I include the above code. I m so confused. Sorry for the trouble dude. But plz help me in this....

Comment: Change your code. Add classes to the divs like I've added for the first div. And then add script events for checkboxes. Remove your previous code and do this. It should probably work